# Reverse Proxy for Firebase Authentification not working - JavaScript Files are blocked

Tags: firebase, nginx, firebase-authentication

I've been playing with my Firebase authentication for two days now and just can't get it to work on iOS.
I decided to use a reverse proxy setting based on this article (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices).

With the below setting, the auth url does get redirected (ex: https://www.url.com/__/auth/) - but no javascript files at that URL (ex: https://www.url.com/__/auth/iframe.js).

It has something to do with my caching setting, once I remove the block for the JavaScript files it works for the most part. There is still a message in the console (Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy would block the window.closed call), but the window is still closed.

Can anyone help me further?

NGINX setting

```
location / {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~* \.(png|jpg|svg|jpeg|bmp|mp4)$ {
    expires 1M;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~* \.(json)$ {
    expires 1w;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# reverse proxy for signin-helpers for popup/redirect sign in.
location /__/auth {
    proxy_pass https://PROJECTID.firebaseapp.com;
}
```